# How to write function correctly

Tags: matlab, function

I'm making a Matlab program for cell growth, 
I have a problem with some function in main.m and I found some functions that I thought are written wrong way:

```
function y = f(c)
y = 0.5*(1-tanh(4*c-2));
function y = h(c) 
y = 0.5*f(c);
function y = g(c)
global beta 
y = beta*exp(beta*c);
%y=1+0.2*c;
```

main.m

```
%%main program
clear; clc;
global alpha beta gamma
%set parameter values
alpha = 0.9; beta = 0.5; gamma = 10;
dx = 1; X = 210; dt = 0.04; T = 16;
c0 = 1;
%set up arrays
x = [dx:dx:X]; Nx = round(X/dx); Nt = round(T/dt);
p = zeros(1,Nx); nextp = zeros(1,Nx);
q = zeros(1,Nx); nextq = zeros(1,Nx);
n = zeros(1,Nx); nextn = zeros(1,Nx);
u = zeros(1,Nx); v = zeros(1,Nx); r = zeros(1,Nx); c = zeros(1,Nx);
P = zeros(Nt,Nx); Q = zeros(Nt,Nx); N = zeros(Nt,Nx);
%set initial values
p = exp(-0.1.*x);
function y = f(c)
y = 0.5*(1-tanh(4*c-2));
function y = h(c)
y = 0.5*f(c);
function y = g(c)
global beta
y = beta*exp(beta*c);
%y=1+0.2*c;

%start FDM time-stepping
for k=1:Nt
    r = p + q;
    c = (c0.*gamma./(gamma+p)).*(1-alpha.*(p+q+n));
    for i=2:Nx-1
        u(i)=((p(i+1)-p(i-1))*r(i)*(r(i+1)-r(i-1))+ 4*p(i)*r(i)*...
            (r(i+1)-2*r(i)+r(i-1))-p(i)*(r(i+1)-r(i-1))^2)/(2*...
            (dx*r(i))^2);
        v(i)=((q(i+1)-q(i-1))*r(i)*(r(i+1)-r(i-1))+ 4*q(i)*r(i)*...
            (r(i+1)-2*r(i)+r(i-1))-q(i)*(r(i+1)-r(i-1))^2)/(2*...
            (dx*r(i))^2);
    end
    nextp=p+dt.*(u+g(c).*p.*(1-(p+q+n))-f(c).*p);
    nextq=q+dt.*(v+f(c).*p-h(c).*q);
    nextn=n+dt.*(h(c).*q);
    p=nextp;
    q=nextq;
    n=nextn;
    P(k,:)=p; Q(k,:)=q; N(k,:)=n;
end
figure(1)
for n=1:500:Nt
    plot(P(n,:),'LineWidth',1.2); hold on;
end
axis([0 270 0 0.6]);
figure(2)
for n=1:500:Nt
    plot(Q(n,:),'LineWidth',1.2); hold on;
end
axis([0 270 0 0.6]);
figure(3)
for n=1:500:Nt
    plot(N(n,:),'LineWidth',1.2); hold on;
end
axis([0 270 0 1]);
```

animation.m

```
%create image for cells
rand('state', sum(100*clock));
prefix='t';
Nm=0;
figure(1)
for n=1:250:Nt
    Nm=Nm+1;
    for i=1:Nx
        tP=round(P(n,i)),tQ=round(Q(n,i)),tN=round(N(n,i));
        for m=1:tP
            theta=2*pi*rand();
            plot(i*sin(theta),i*cos(theta),'b.'); hold on;
        end
        for m=1:tQ
            theta=2*pi*rand();
            plot(i*sin(theta),i*cos(theta),'r.'); hold on;
        end
        for m=1:tN
            theta=2*pi*rand();
            plot(i*sin(theta),i*cos(theta),'k.'); hold on;
        end
        axis square
        axis([-300 300 -300 300])
    end
    print('-djpeg','-r100',sprintf('%s_%s',prefix,num2str(Nm)));
end

clear MM
for i=1:Nm
    [XX,map]=imread(sprintf('%s_%s',prefix,num2str(i)),'jpeg');
    imagesc(XX);
    MM(i)=getframe;
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Please help me solve this problem..

Comment: Please be more specific - which function is 'some'? Go through your code with a debugger and try to find the solution yourself first. Also, have a look at [how to ask good, on-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (1) **NB: read [ask]**. (2) At the very least, indent your code! (3) please narrow down your code to only the relevant portions (4) you need to actually explain what problems you are having. Be specific, point out the exact lines of code where there are problems and if there are errors then include the error message verbatim. If there aren't errors then you must clearly describe what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're main.m is a script, not a function (it doesn't start with the word function), see [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and [Scripts vs. Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html)).

In short: function declaration is not allowed in command-line or scripts only in function files. 
Do as oro777 advises,
create a seperate file for each function.

Another way is to turn your main.m into a function too, by starting it with `function main`. Then decleration of additional functions is allowed in the same file, but these are all local functions which means they will only be available from within that file. You can not call them from outside the file they were declared in.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the output error so we can see which function is badly written. At first view, I would say you should use longer function names because with only one letter, it may easily shadow with a variable name and I would advise not to use global variables.

I see that your functions are defined in the same file as the main program, I would advise to create one function per file. For example a f_function m-file with the following code.

```
function y = f_function(c)
    y = 0.5*(1-tanh(4*c-2));
```

Do the same for your two other functions and place your newly created m-files in the same folder as your main program.